# How long does a payment take to appear in my wallet, If not how do I reacieave it?

Tags: bitcore

Yes how long does it take for a payment to appear in my wallet, on Bitcore, if it doesnt how do I reacieve it? Because it's been 15 hours but still havent seen it

Comment: Bitcore, or bitcoin core? Is your wallet fully synchronized? Do you have a transaction ID?

Answer (score 1):

Most wallets will show you incoming/outgoing transactions as soon as they appear on the network. If you are not seeing a transaction, it is possible that your node (if you're using Bitcoin Core or a similar full client) is not fully synced yet, or that the node your light wallet connects to isn't fully synced. You can fix this by either waiting for your node to sync, or connecting to one that is synced.

During times when the mempool is full, nodes might drop transactions with low fees depending on how large their mempool is. At the time of writing, the mempool is quite empty, so this should not affect you.

If you are using a hosted wallet such as blockchain.info or an exchange, their systems may have not been able to detect your transaction, and you should reach out to their customer service.

You can also ask the sender for the tx id and use a block explorer to verify that the transaction has been confirmed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node wallet then you dont need to worry about your coins as the pvt key is with you,using which you can get your coins back. Generally it wont take more than the blockformation time  which is 10min(approx) if your node of fully synchronised with bitcoin blockchain else you might have to wait till your node is sync. 
You can keep trace of your transaction [here](http://blockchain.info).